# Построить правильно regex fail2ban

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения

Нужно построить выражение для fail2ban основываясь на этой строчке:

```
 [18:45:35] BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249
```

Такое не работает:

```
^/[.*/] BAD ATTEMPT: <HOST>$
```

Comment: Я бы удивился, заработай оно

    ^\[\d+:\d+:\d+\] BAD ATTEMPT: (?:\d+\.){3}\d+$

Comment: Fail2ban не может прочесть формат времени, выдает:
Found a match for '[18:45:35] BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249
' but no valid date/time found for '[18:45:35] BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249
'. Please contact the author in order to get support for this format

Вот если строка имеет вид такой:
18:45:35 BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249
То все ок, а нужна регулярка под которую я указал

Comment: @Etki а как же экранирование метасимволов `[]` ? То же самое относится и к afonasievitch. Экранируйте метасимволы. Если `<HOST>` - допустимое выражение, то выражение в вопросе нормальное за исключением незаэкранированных символов.

Comment: Вы абсолютно уверены, что экранирование идет с `/` а не с `\ ` ? Я не берусь утверждать, ибо диалектов регексов тьма, но ни разу не встречал экранирование `/`

Comment: Блин. Некровопрос :( Подстава :(

Comment: Тест `/` внутри `\` текст далее

Comment: @ReinRaus: за некровопросы есть некрознак ))

Answer (score 3):

> Fail2ban не может прочесть формат времени, выдает: Found a match for '[18:45:35] BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249 ' but no valid date/time found for '[18:45:35] BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249 '. Please contact the author in order to get support for this format Вот если строка имеет вид такой: 18:45:35 BAD ATTEMPT: 178.234.102.249 То все ок, а нужна регулярка под которую я указал

из [документации](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters) к программе:

> The pattern or regex to match the time stamp is currently not documented, and not available for users to read or set. See [Debian bug #491253](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=491253%7C). This is a problem if your log has a timestamp format that fail2ban doesn't expect, since it will then fail to match any lines. Because of this, you should test any new failregex against a sample log line, as in the examples below, to be sure that it will match. **If fail2ban doesn't recognize your log timestamp, then you have two options: either reconfigure your daemon to log with a timestamp in a more common format, such as in the example log line above; or file a bug report asking to have your timestamp format included**.

вольный перевод:

> шаблон для поиска отметок времени сейчас не документирован и недоступен пользователю для чтения или изменения. см. [debian bug #491253](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=491253%7C). это проблема, если ваш лог-файл содержит отметки времени в формате, непонятном программе *fail2ban*, потому что она в результате не распознает ни одной строки в логе. ... **если fail2ban не распознаёт отметки времени вашего лога, у вас два пути: либо переконфигурировать программу, записывающую лог (чтобы она писала в более распространённом формате), либо отослать сообщение об ошибке автору fail2ban с просьбой включить в программу ваш особый формат отметок времени.**

---

от себя лично добавлю: т.к. речь о свободном программном обеспечении, то есть ещё два пути — либо самому разобраться в коде программы и внести необходимые изменения, либо нанять/заинтересовать того, кто сможет это сделать за вас.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего Вы неправильно экранируете символы `[]`. Не тем слэшем.
Должно быть так:

```
^\[.*\] BAD ATTEMPT: <HOST>$
```